# How do I remove a table embedded in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have the unfortunate task of debugging a large Microsoft Word document that has unwanted page breaks after some paragraphs. The spaces in question previously contained an image, but remained after the image was removed. The "show/hide formatting characters" button shows nothing out of the ordinary, the paragraph settings don't have anything unusual in them, and there are no manual break (^m) characters in the document. I have noticed what appears to be a hidden table however.

If I start with the cursor immediately at the end of the paragraph before the break, and press the right arrow key, it jumps to the beginning of the paragraph after the break, and the delete and backspace keys will not delete the object. However, if I double click in the middle of the break, it will display a cursor centered in the page and allow me to type. Additionally, if I click the button that draws a border around the current object, it will draw a border around the line of text like you would see with a table cell. When I have the cursor in this cell though, Word does not display any table editing options, and I have no way of selecting the border around the object and deleting it.

Has anybody experienced this problem before? Is it a table that has been embedded in the document? Most importantly, how do I delete this unwanted page break?

Comment: Can you see it in `print view`? What if you press Alt+F9?

Comment: The spaces show up in all views, but none of them have anything that appears to represent the table in them. Alt+F9 doesn't display the object either.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor to the paragraph mark before the mystery object.  Press Enter to add another paragraph, also before the mystery object.  Now go to the paragraph after the object and insert a new empty paragraph at the beginning - before the text. You now have empty paragraphs before and after the object to be deleted.

Starting from the first empty paragraph mark, hold down shift and cursor down to the second empty paragraph, highlighting the two paragraphs and every thing in between. Click the "cut" button on the Ribbon (the scissors icon).  That should delete everything you don't want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I hit enter to create a new paragraph, nothing appears to happen and the text stays in the same place. If I attempt to take a little bit of text before and after the space (copying the text into notepad) it appears to remove the page break, but then it re-appears when the text is pasted, or even typed, back into the document.

Comment: Hmmm...  If you would be comfortable letting me see the document, I would take a look at it and I'm sure I can figure out the problem.  My email address is in my profile.